# Checking for login on html page

Tags: php, html, session

So i have a login.php that starts a sessions and sets 'login', then redirects the user to a html page (pTable.html) like this:

```html
<?ph
//starting session
session_start();
//connecting to database and such
echo $_SESSION['login'];
define('DB_NAME', '');
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
 die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mainLogin WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($count==1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($password == $row['password']){ 
//IMPORTANT PART
//IMPORTANT PART
//IMPORTANT PART
//IMPORTANT PART
      $_SESSION["login"] = $username;
      echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://madsanker.dk.linux101.unoeuro-server.com/ptable/pTable.html'); </script>";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://madsanker.dk.linux101.unoeuro-server.com'); </script>";
        return false;
    }
}
else{
    echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://madsanker.dk.linux101.unoeuro-server.com'); </script>";
    return false;
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

And i am cheking for the session variable in my html file like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  exit();
}
?>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pTableStylesheet.css">
<title>Periodic Table</title>
<head>
<script src="script.js" type=text/javascript></script>
<p id=welcome>Welcome to our Periodic Table Of Elements.<br>
  ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

when i go to the ptable.html page from a browser that i have not logged in to, i should be redirected to the error page right?

This is not working. Can anyone see why?

Thanks.

Comment: your php code will run at ptable.html ? change it to ptable.php and, redirect to login page if not logged in with php header.

Comment: @LearningMode Can i just change that? Will all the html code still work?

Comment: yes definitely your all html will work

Comment: @LearningMode Thanks! I didn't know that. I am very new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your file name from `ptable.html` to `ptable.php` to run php code.

and use below code to redirect to login.php if not logged in and if try to access ptable page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
  header("Location: login.php");
exit();
}
```

Also change link or action where ever you used ptable.html to ptable.php